# jquery validation error label

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I have a text field defined as below. When the validation error displayed, its not showing as horizontal. It is limiting to the length of the zip field. Could someone tell me how to fix the problem? Please see the attached images.

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">Policy Search</h3></div>
 <div class="panel-body">
  <div class ="form-group">                                         
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" >Policy Number</label>      
<div class="col-sm-3">    
 <input  class="text-input form-control" type="text" name="policyNumber" id="policyNumber" />                                           
</div>      
  </div>
  <div class ="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" >Last Name</label>     
<div class="col-sm-3">    
<input  class="text-input form-control" type="text" name="phLastName" id="phLastName" />                                            
</div>
  </div>
  <div class ="form-group">
   <label for="Zip" class="col-sm-2 control-label"  >Zip</label>        
<div class="col-sm-1">    
<input  class="text-input form-control" id="zip" type="text" name="Zip" maxlength="5" size="5" />                                           
</div>
   </div>       
   <div class="col-sm-2">&nbsp;</div>                           
   <div class="col-sm-2">    
<button type="button" name="search" id="search" class="btn btn-success">Search Policy</button>                                          
</div>                                                                               
   </div> <!--  End of panel Body -->       
  </div><!--  End of panel  -->
 </div> <!-- End of search panel div -->
```

In debug mode, the HTML code looks like this :

I am not able to add the image. Basically the zip field is 5 characters in length. When the error is displayed:

"This field is required"

It displays below the zip text field."

row 1: "This field" below this second line "is" below this third line "Required". I wish i could add an image

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/q6As7/6/)

[image: Policy Search]

[image: In debug mode]

Comment: Not sure why I am not ot able to add png files

Comment: I guess col-sm-1 has small width, put the error label out that div. add all the html code, and also the css, will be easier to answer.

Comment: Any idea why I am not able to add images  to my post?

Comment: I have updated my post with more html code.

Comment: please include the styles applied .. a http://www.jsfiddle.net would be helpfull

Comment: Are you using any javascript? maybe a jquery pluging? and are you using any css style sheet? add it to. you can solve this problem only with css, but i need to know what are you using.

Comment: We need the CSS that's relevant in order to tell what's going on here.

Comment: I have added JS fiddle. Please take a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The JS fiddle Does not show the same as the picture, but what you need is to add some css to your code. col-sm-1 width should be 100% and set a static width to the zip input, do it on a css file or on your html file.

```
.col-sm-1{ width: 100% !important; }
#zip{ width: 80px;}
```

on html

```
<input  class="text-input form-control" id="zip" type="text" name="Zip" maxlength="5" size="5" style="width:80px;" />
```

Comment: Here is updated fiddle. Please take a look. It is not aligining correctly. http://jsfiddle.net/q6As7/5/

Comment: Instead of expanding this zip field to 80%, is there anyway in general adding the error message in a new seperate line below the element ? like errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
         
           var test = $(element).closest('span').next().find('.error_label').html(error);
           alert(test);
      },

Comment: I may have some cutome messages that are longer than the legthe of the tex feild. So I ma thinking in general, if i can have a genera lroutine to add a span or div just for displaying error message would solve the problem. Thanksfor helping on this!